# ошибка при запуске "куча была повреждена"

Tags: c++

Имею код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include "methods.h"
#include "functions.h"
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
using int128_t = boost::multiprecision::int128_t;

typedef int128_t matrix[2][2];

void mul(matrix a, matrix b, matrix c, int128_t mod)
{
    int n = 2;
    matrix d;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            int128_t s = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
                s = (s + a[i][k] * b[k][j]) % mod;
            ((c == a || c == b) ? d[i][j] : c[i][j]) = s;
        }
    if (c == a || c == b)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                c[i][j] = d[i][j];
}

void power(matrix i, int128_t p, matrix&r, int128_t mod)
{
    int n = 2;
    if (p % 2)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
                r[j][k] = i[j][k];
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
                r[j][k] = (j == k) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    while (p /= 2)
    {
        mul(i, i, i, mod);
        if (p % 2) mul(i, r, r, mod);
    }
}

vector<int128_t> Schirokauer_Maps(int128_t a, int128_t b, int128_t h, int128_t q)
{
    int128_t q1 = pow(q, 2);
    vector<int128_t> s(2);
    matrix ax, r;
    ax[0][0] = a;
    ax[0][1] = h;
    ax[1][0] = b;
    ax[1][1] = a - b;

    power(ax, q - 1, r, q1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            if (r[i][j] < 0)
                r[i][j] += q1;

    s[0] = (r[0][0] - 1) / q;
    s[1] = r[1][0] / q;

    return s;
}

int64_t number(uint64_t h, uint64_t g, uint64_t p, uint64_t m1)  //p-модуль, g-основание, h-ответ, d-степень для взятия корня
{
    int d = 2;
    vector<int> prime{ 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541,547,557,563,569,571,577,587,593,599,601,607,613,617,619,631,641,643,647,653,659,661,673,677,683,691,701,709,719,727,733,739,743,751,757,761,769,773,787,797,809,811,821,823,827,829,839,853,857,859,863,877,881,883,887,907,911,919,929,937,941,947,953,967,971,977,983,991,997,1009,1013,1019 };
    int128_t q = p, ts = p;
    int128_t qs = (p - 1) / 2;
    mp::cpp_bin_float_quad N = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int128_t quantity_prime = 0;
    int128_t t = 0;
    int128_t w = 0; // счетчик коэффицентов
                    //int128_t m = mp::pow(p, 1.0 / d);
    int128_t m = mp::sqrt(p);
    vector<int128_t> equation(d + 1);
    //построение уравнения
    for (i = d; i > 0; i--)
    {
        do {
            q = q - mp::pow(m, int(i));
            w++;
        } while (q - pow(m, int(i)) > 0);
        equation[int(i)] = w;
        w = 0;
    }
    equation[0] = q;

    //выделение памяти под базисы
    int128_t b = 8;
    do
    {
        i++;
        t = prime[int(i)];
    } while (t < b);

    vector <pair<int128_t, int128_t> > rational_factor;
    vector <pair<int128_t, int128_t> > algebraic_factor;
    i = 0;
    t = 0;

    //расчет рационального базиса:
    q = prime[0];
    ts = prime[0];
    do {
        do
        {
            rational_factor.push_back(make_pair(m%q, q));
            i++;
            q = prime[int(i)];
        } while (b > q);
        //расчет алгебраического базиса:
        w = 0; //для расчета уравнения
        int128_t y = 0;
        do
        {
            for (int128_t iw = 0; iw < ts; iw++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < equation.size(); j++)
                    w += equation[j] * pow(iw, j);
                if (w%ts == 0)
                {
                    algebraic_factor.push_back(make_pair(iw, ts));
                    y++;
                }
                w = 0;
            }
            t++;
            ts = prime[int(t)];
        } while (b > ts);
        if ((i == prime.size() - 1) || t == prime.size() - 1)
            return -1;
    } while (algebraic_factor.size() != rational_factor.size());

    b = 2 * algebraic_factor.size() + 3;

    //построение матрицы
    int128_t ij = 1;
    vector<vector<int128_t>> mas(b.convert_to<size_t>(), vector<int128_t>(b.convert_to<size_t>(), 0));
    pair<int128_t, int128_t> ab;
    int o = 0;
    vector <pair<int128_t, int128_t> > pairs(m.convert_to<size_t>());
    bool a = true;

    srand(time(0)); // автоматическая рандомизация
    int128_t d0 = 0, d1 = 0, d2 = 0, d3 = 0;

    do {

        //генерация a и b проверка на нод и вхождения
        do {
            ab.first = rand() % (2 * m1) + 1; // диапазон равен от 1 до 3 включительно
            ab.second = rand() % (2 * m1 + 1) + (-m1);
            int128_t i = 0;

            if (NOD(ab.first, ab.second) != 1)
                a = false;
            else if (find(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), ab) == pairs.end())
            {
                a = true;
                pairs[o] = ab;
                o++;
            }
            else a = false;
            if (a == true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rational_factor.size(); i++)
                {
                    d0 = -rational_factor[i].first*ab.second%rational_factor[i].second;
                    d3 = ab.first%rational_factor[i].second;
                    if (d0 < 0)
                        d0 += rational_factor[i].second;
                    if (d3 < 0)
                        d3 += rational_factor[i].second;
                    if (d3 == d0)
                        d1++;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < algebraic_factor.size(); i++)
                {
                    d0 = -algebraic_factor[i].first*ab.second%algebraic_factor[i].second;
                    d3 = ab.first%algebraic_factor[i].second;

                    if (d0 < 0)
                        d0 += algebraic_factor[i].second;

                    if (d3 < 0)
                        d3 += algebraic_factor[i].second;

                    if (d3 == d0)
                        d2++;
                }
                if ((d1 == 0) || (d2 == 0))
                {
                    pairs[o].first = 0;
                    pairs[o].second = 0;
                    o--;
                }
            }
        } while ((a == false) || (d1 == 0) || (d2 == 0));

        //процесс заполнения матрицы
        int128_t summa = 0;
        int128_t yup = 0;

        summa = ab.first + ab.second*m;

        if (summa == 0)
            yup = rational_factor.size();

        if (summa < 0)
        {
            mas[0][ij.convert_to<size_t>()] = 1;
            summa *= -1;
        }
        while (yup != rational_factor.size())
        {
            if (summa % rational_factor[yup.convert_to<size_t>()].second == 0)
            {
                summa /= rational_factor[yup.convert_to<size_t>()].second;
                mas[(yup + 1).convert_to<size_t>()][ij.convert_to<size_t>()]++;
            }
            else
                yup++;
        }
        int128_t i = 0;
        //yup++;
        mp::cpp_bin_float_quad as = (mp::cpp_bin_float_quad) - ab.first / ab.second.convert_to<mp::cpp_bin_float_quad>();
        for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
            N += equation[j].convert_to<mp::cpp_bin_float_quad>() * pow(as, j);
        N = N * mp::pow(-ab.second, d).convert_to<mp::cpp_bin_float_quad>();

        if (N == 0 || summa == 0)
            i = algebraic_factor.size();
        while (i < algebraic_factor.size())
        {
            d0 = -algebraic_factor[int(i)].first*ab.second%algebraic_factor[int(i)].second;
            d3 = ab.first%algebraic_factor[int(i)].second;

            if (d0 < 0)
                d0 += algebraic_factor[int(i)].second;

            if (d3 < 0)
                d3 += algebraic_factor[int(i)].second;

            if (d3 == d0)
                do {
                    if ((int128_t)N % algebraic_factor[int(i)].second == 0)
                    {
                        N /= algebraic_factor[int(i)].second.convert_to<mp::cpp_bin_float_quad>();
                        mas[(yup + 1).convert_to<size_t>()][ij.convert_to<size_t>()]++;
                    }
                } while ((int128_t)N % algebraic_factor[int(i)].second == 0);
                i++;
                yup++;
        }
        if (N == 1 && summa == 1)
        {
            vector<int128_t> mapk = Schirokauer_Maps(ab.first, ab.second, -equation[0] * ab.second, qs);
            int128_t y = 0;
            for (int u = algebraic_factor.size() * 2 + 1; u < b; u++, y++)
                mas[u][ij.convert_to<size_t>()] = mapk[y.convert_to<size_t>()];
            ij++;
        }
        else
        {
            pairs[o].first = 0;
            pairs[o].second = 0;
            o--;
            for (int k = 0; k<b; k++)
                mas[k][ij.convert_to<size_t>()] = 0;
        }
        N = 0;
    } while (ij != b);

    //добавляем 1 строку в начало и ответ системы
    vector<int128_t> rezult(b.convert_to<size_t>());
    int128_t G = 0;
    int128_t H = 0;
    int128_t S = 0;
    int128_t R = 0;
    int128_t yup = 0;
    do {
        S = rand() % qs + 10;
        G = int128_t(powmod(g, S, p));
        while (yup != rational_factor.size())
        {
            if (G % rational_factor[yup.convert_to<size_t>()].second == 0)
            {
                G /= rational_factor[yup.convert_to<size_t>()].second;
                mas[(yup + 1).convert_to<size_t>()][0]++;
            }
            else
                yup++;
        }
        if (G != 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<b; i++)
                mas[i][0] = 0;
        }
        yup = 0;
    } while (G != 1);
    yup = 0;
    do {
        R = rand() % qs + 10;
        H = int128_t(powmod(g, R, p)*h) % p;
        while (yup != rational_factor.size())
        {
            if (H % rational_factor[yup.convert_to<size_t>()].second == 0)
            {
                H /= rational_factor[yup.convert_to<size_t>()].second;
                rezult[(yup + 1).convert_to<size_t>()]++;
            }
            else
                yup++;
        }
        yup = 0;
        if (H != 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<b; i++)
                rezult[i] = 0;
        }
    } while (H != 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        if (rezult[i] != 0)
            rezult[i] = -rezult[i] + qs;
    }

    auto resh = gauss(mas, rezult, b, qs);
    int128_t k = 0;
    int128_t k1 = 0;
    int64_t x = 0;
    /*do {
    if (k == resh.size())
    return -1;
    x = (-resh[k][0] * S - R) % qs;
    if (x < 0)
    x += qs;
    k++;
    } while (powmod(g, x, p) != h);*/
    k1 = (-resh[k.convert_to<size_t>()][0] * S - R) % qs;
    x = k1.convert_to<int64_t>();
    if (x < 0)
        x += uint64_t(qs);
    return x;
}
```

Когда собираю ошибок нет, но как только начинаеться запуск выдает ошибку:

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FFDB2D4879B (ntdll.dll) в
>   all_metods.exe: 0xC0000374: Куча была повреждена (параметры:
>   0x00007FFDB2DAC6E0).

**update**
в debug выдает ошибку:

> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FFDB2CC7670 (ntdll.dll) в
>   all_metods.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по
>   адресу 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Comment: В какой строке ошибка?

Comment: Не показывает, когда компилируешь нет ошибок. При отладке выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Поьзуетесь бустом, а   программируете в стиле С. Не рыбо, не мясо

Comment: я пока тренируюсь)

Comment: По callstack-у вы можете увидеть в какой строке вашей программы ошибка.

Comment: Проект собирается без ошибок

Comment: Так вы отладчик запустите... А вообще код - полный винегрет.

Comment: Не спорю, на то я новичок) вроде в debug запускаю

Comment: Просто без библиотеки boost все компилируется и работает

Comment: Вы где-то выделили память, а места под данные не хватило, вы продолжили писать в память выйдя за границы, вот вам и выдает ошибку о поврежденной куче. Смотрите места где вы выделяете память, и где пишите данные.

Comment: Она же даже не запускается, как я могу записывать в память?

Comment: Что-то какая-то мешанина, прости.

Comment: Почему код мешанина?

Comment: Запустите под отладчиком и вы найдете место ошибки https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k0k771bt.aspx

Comment: Есть ощущение, что код неполный - нет `main()` или иной точки входа. Ошибка при запуске (до первой "настоящей" строчки кода) обычно означает, что что-то пошло не так при инициализации, например, глобальных переменных.

Comment: Скорее всего, где-то в коде вы вышли за пределы массива или вектора. Вы бы скинули ссылку на проект